# префиксные и постфиксный ++ от яндекс практикума

Tags: c++, производительность, операторы, инкремент

на сколько корректно выражение

> Инкременты и декременты бывают также постфиксные. Префиксные меняют значения переменных до обработки компилятором, а постфиксные — после. Поэтому префиксные более производительны.

меня смущает фраза до отработки компилятором.
и правда ли префиксный быстрее? хорошо бы на стандарт.
я посмотрел под диз асемблером в циклах код один в один. При присвоении переменной на одну ассемблерную команду больше.
Зависит ли это от опций компилятора ?

Comment: Да, фраза явно неправильно построена и не соответствует действительности. Что касается прозводительности - тоже ложь.

Comment: Почему ложь, одних часных случаев справедливо, для других нет. Просто операция инкремент (без присваивания) в чистом виде в обычных случаях (для int32) выполняется за один такт процессора (а то и меньше), поэтому о производительности есть смысл говорить когда обрабатываются большие массивы данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a потому что, если вы используете постинкремент там, где он не нужен, то вы используете не то средство. Точно так же можно сравнить производительность сложения с вызовом здоровенной функции. Если же постинкремент необходим, то при "ручной" реализации его через префиксный инкремент, вы получите тот же самый код. И да, если постинкремент не нужен, то компилятор, скорее всего, его всё равно выкинет.

Comment: Дизассемблер прав, автор слов нет (может быть когда-то в каком-то самопальном компайлере кто-то это и видел и с тех пор идет эта деза)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понимаете, тут не хватает "в общем случае".

Что толку в сравнении выражений `++i` и `i++` для простого `int`? Где само значение выражения не используется, так что весь эффект - только в увеличении переменной на 1...

А если это что-то посерьезнее, то префиксный просто увеличивает значение, а вот постфиксный должен еще и старое значение сохранить, а потом вернуть. Чувствуете разницу? :)

Вот - как пример - даже для простого `int` без оптимизации VC++ обрабатывает по-разному:

```
; 15   :     cout << ++i;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    add ecx, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], ecx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    push    edx
    mov ecx, OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<

; 16   :     cout << i++;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR tv72[ebp], eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    add ecx, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], ecx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR tv72[ebp]
    push    edx
    mov ecx, OFFSET ?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
```

Видите - временную переменную `tv` для хранения?

А если это какой-то пользовательский класс?..

Comment: "А если это какой-то пользовательский класс?" - то постфиксный оператор, выполняющий сложение двух интов, будет работать быстрее префиксного, выполняющего запрос в базу данных. )))

Comment: @Croessmah Мы же, надеюсь, говорим о семантически непротиворечивых операторах? Люди мы опытные, и навешивать на операторы несвойственную им функциональность, как совсем зеленые, не станем?...

Comment: конечно, но мы же понимаем, что постфиксный и префиксный операторы выполняют разную работу. :)

Comment: с классами понятно там всё зависит от реализации. Если я правильно понял то вся разница в том что с постфиксным  создаётся временная переменная. И действительно товарищи с яндекса правы и предпочтительнее использовать префиксный инкремент ?

Comment: Отнюдь. Если вы нормальный программист, то ваши префиксный и постфиксный операторы ++ будут отличаться одним - тем, что префиксный будет возвращать измененное значение, а постфиксный - сохраненное. Если вы будете переопределять семантику префиксного и постфиксного операторов по-разному  - это будет означать одно: вы еще не программист...